# nservicebus deleting subscription record after inserting it?

Tags: nhibernate, nservicebus

I have been playing with nservicebus for a few weeks now and since everything was going well on my local machine I decided to try to set up a test environment and work on deployment. I am using the generic host that comes with nservicebus and was using the nservicebus.Integration profile when running locally, but would like to use Nservicebus.Production in the test environment. I set up a sql server 2008 database, made changes to my app.config and everything seemed to work fine. But after a few attempts, I noticed messages were not being picked up by my subscriber. I checked the subscription table and it was empty. Upon examination of the logs I noticed the following:

> 2010-05-06 15:07:57,416 [1] DEBUG NHibernate.Persister.Entity.AbstractEntityPers
>   ister [(null)] <(null)> -  Insert 0: INSERT INTO [Subscription] (SubscriberEndpo
>   int, MessageType) VALUES (?, ?)
>   2010-05-06 15:07:57,416 [1] DEBUG NHibernate.Persister.Entity.AbstractEntityPers
>   ister [(null)] <(null)> -  Update 0:
>   2010-05-06 15:07:57,416 [1] DEBUG NHibernate.Persister.Entity.AbstractEntityPers
>   ister [(null)] <(null)> -  Delete 0: DELETE FROM [Subscription] WHERE Subscriber
>   Endpoint = ? AND MessageType = ?

Why would it insert then delete my subscription right afterwards? To try to rule out a nhibernate dialect issue I tried switching my subscription storage to an oracle 10g database. It behaved exactly the same, it worked the first 2 times, then I started seeing my subscriptions being deleted right after they were inserted. Any ideas what is causing this behavior?

Comment: I was using nservicebus 2.0.0.945. I am upgrading to 2.0.0.1145 to see if that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not run into this issue since upgrading to version 2.0.0.1145. I have not made any other changes (besides logging config) so I'm assuming this was a bug with the previous version.

Answer (score 0):

Delete only occurs when the subscriber receives a request to unsubscribe. Can you verify that you're not calling bus.Unsubscribe anywhere in your code?

Comment: Yes, I did a search for unsubscribe in the entire solution and found nothing. Also, this was working with the NServicebus.Integration profile.